# Referring to an Answer of One's Own

Tags: discussion

I added in a previous question a hyperlink to an answer
 from a question which was also mine. Is this a kind of self-referencing? I wondered if this was discouraged.

Thank you

Comment: Are you referring to the hyperlink in [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/35331/254)? If so, what could be wrong with that?

Comment: I'm not sure now, maybe I was just overthinking this haha. And yes, it was that one.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a slight worry -- not especially about the content of your posts, which I haven't reviewed in detail -- but only about posting "too many" questions, e.g. 3 of the most recent 5 are yours.

Your questions don't seem to me to be rude at all, and they're not downvoted -- but we might each, as users, try to avoid overwhelming the site's community with too many questions.

My main worry -- as a person, not as a moderator -- isn't that your posts are deliberately self-aggrandising or hostile; it's only that if you keep asking questions I'm not sure whether the previous questions and answers did any good, were helpful.

---

To answer your specific question, I think it's good behaviour -- and not discouraged -- to post a follow-up question if there's something in an answer which you don't understand ... that is, if it deserves to be asked as a new/separate question, instead of e.g. posting a comment to ask the OP to clarify their existing answer to the original question.